# Update dictionary while condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, while-loop

I am working on a code that given a dictionary of dictionaries which looks like this:

```
D = {1: {2: 'a', 3: 'b'}, 10: {11: 'a', 12: 'b'}}
```

where 1 and 2 are keys while inner dictionaries {2: 'a', 3: 'b'} and {11: 'a', 12: 'b'} are results after applying an addition of 1 or 2. D[1] + 1 = 2 and D[1] + 2 = 3. 'a' and 'b' indicates an addition to 1 or 2 respectively.

From D I'd like to keep applying those additions to its new products which I can get by doing this:

```
products = list(set([l for x, y in D.items() for l, m in y.items()]))

products = [2,3,11,12]
```

I use a set list just to avoid apply additions on products that already are on D.

So applying additions to every item in product and add them to D will end up in something like this:

```
D = {1: {2: 'a', 3: 'b'}, 10: {11: 'a', 12: 'b'}, 2: {3: 'a', 4: 'b'}, 3: {4: 'a', 5: 'b'}, 11: {12: 'a', 13: 'b'}, 12: {13: 'a', 14: 'b'}}
```

Note the new keys and its new inner dictionaries (products)

The thing is that I'd like to keep doing this with new products in a while loop until a number is achieved.

For instance for the next iteration products will be:

```
products = [3,4,5,12,13,14]
```

They should be used to apply additions if they are not in D, so this can be easily done by:

```
for i in products:
    if i in D:
        products.remove(i)
```

which will lead us to:

```
products = [4,5,13,14] # 3 and 12 are already on D
```

So  we should apply addition to these products and add them to D

So I guess that to achieve this there must be something like:

```
D = {1: {2: 'a', 3: 'b'}, 10: {11: 'a', 12: 'b'}}
i = 0
while i < 4: # just an example of 4 number of iterations
    products = list(set([l for x, y in D.items() for l, m in y.items()]))
    for j in products:
        if j in D:
            products.remove(j)
    # apply additions
    # update D or use an auxiliary dict and them append to D



    i +=1
```

Comment: You can use dict.setdefault, it will only add an element in the dict if it doesn't already exists. So that you don't have to care if the element is already there.

Comment: Could you provide an example for this application?

Answer (score 0):

There's just a single variable `i`, there.

You'll want to use `for j` on the inner loop,
to avoid disturbing the outer loop.